# Instance variables in Smalltalk Vs java

Tags: java, encapsulation, smalltalk, instance-variables, getter-setter

In Pharo by Example Book,  I read

> Instance variables in Smalltalk are private to the instance itself.
>   This is in contrast to Java and C++, which allow instance variables
>   (also known as “fields” or “member variables”) to be accessed by any
>   other instance that happens to be of the same class.

I think it is common to other languages like Java or c# also . An instance of class cannot access instance variable of another instance of same class. ***How it is specific to smalltalk only ?***

> In Smalltalk, two instances of the same class cannot access each other’s
>   instance variables unless the class defines “accessor methods”

***How can an instance access another instance's instance variable using accessor method ?***

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
class car {
  private:
    int mileage;
  public:
    car(int); // Constructor
    int odometer();
};

car::car(int m) {
  mileage = m;
}

int car::odometer() {
  return mileage;
}

int main(void) {
  car ford(10000);
  car honda(20000);

  cout<<ford.odometer(); 
  cout<<honda.odometer();
}
```

In this example ford and honda are two instances of the same class `Car`. ***How ford can use the mileage of honda object or vice versa*** ? This is my actual question. Sorry if this is so naive

Comment: I've read answers and further in the Pharo By example book. I came to understand that In C++ and java an instance can access other instance's instance variable according to its access modifier level, if private then it can be accessed with in class, if public then it can be accessed anywhere. But in Smalltalk we cant do within class or wherever. Maximum encapsulation provided by java, C++ is up to class level only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I think it is common to other languages like Java or c# also . An instance of class cannot access instance variable of another instance of same class. How it is specific to smalltalk only ?

Sorry, but this thinking is incorrect.

In Java, an instance of a class *can* access the private fields of another instance of the same class.

For a class `Point` with two fields `x` and `y`, a common implementation of the `equals` method (in fact generated by Intellij) is:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Point point = (Point) o;

    if (x != point.x) return false;
    if (y != point.y) return false;

    return true;
}
```

In this, the current object is accessing the fields of the other object `point` directly, as would not be allowed in Smalltalk.

This is also allowed in C# and many other languages.  Whether Smalltalk is really the only language disallowing it I'm not sure.

By convention, the accessors of a Smalltalk class frequently are the same as the instance variable, but you need to actually write the accessors, and there is no syntax for accessing fields on a different instance directly.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this Java code:

```
public class Person {
    Integer wallet = new Integer(100);
}
```

and run the Thief class:

```
public class Thief {
    Person victim = new Person();

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Thief thief = new Thief();
        System.out.println("I take $"+ thief.victim.wallet + " from your wallet!");
    }
}
```

The result is: **I take $100 from your wallet!**

It does not even have to be an instance of the same class.

In case you declare a Java variable as **private**, instances of the same class could still access each other's instance variables. If you adapt the above example, a thief could still steal from another thief:

```
public class Thief {
    private Integer wallet = new Integer(100);

    public Thief victim() {
        Thief victim = new Thief();
        return victim;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Thief thief = new Thief();
        System.out.println("I take $"+ thief.victim().wallet + " from your wallet!");
    }
}
```

This is not possible in Smalltalk.

Comment: If we declare wallet as private in java then we can achieve same thing as in smalltalk. Isn't it ? so in that book they are saying In smalltalk the scope of instance variable is by default private. Am I correct ?

Comment: In this case a thief can only steal from another thief :) Now the _same class_ condition applies.

Comment: @Sankaran No, you cannot declare that way in Java, each other instance of the same class (or inner classes through bridge methods) can access your instance's private fields/methods. In Scala for example there is a distinction of `private[this]` (Smalltalk way) and `private` (Java way).

Comment: @MartinW Your comment is correct, though your answer seems to be about the default visibility, not the private what the question was about.

Comment: @GáborBakos  I extended my answer. But in the question, the word _private_ appears only in relation to Smalltalk variables, not as Java access modifier.

Comment: @MartinW I meant private as Java access modifier only

Comment: Ok, i extended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> This is in contrast to Java and C++, which allow instance variables to be accessed by any other instance that happens to be of the **same** class.

It's true.